# Issue while integrating Paytm Payment gateway in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, cfnetwork, paytm

I'm integrating paytm payment gateway in iOS. I've all the required details such as MID, merchant key etc from Paytm end. I've obtained generate checksum and verify checksum url from server end too.

Now when I'm calling SDK it is redirecting me to main paytm page and not on transaction or wallet page.
Also I'm receiving following warnings in console area:

**CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)**

Anyone having any idea regarding this?

Comment: did you add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to your Info.plist?

Comment: @ivarun: yes these lines are already added to info.plist file.
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>